# MySql hexadecimal using 0x notation

Tags: mysql, sql, hex

```
SELECT 0x0a+0;
```

returns 10.

why does

```
SELECT 0x0a;
```

return nothing?

Is there a chart on how to write correct hexadecimal literals. Any official references relevant mysql manual would be appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) is quite clear on this:

> In numeric contexts, hexadecimal values act like integers (64-bit
>   precision). In string contexts, they act like binary strings, where
>   each pair of hex digits is converted to a character:

The first case is a numeric context, so it gets treated as a number.

The second is context-less which is equivalent to a string context (at least in this case).  The character with ASCII value 10 is a linefeed, and you won't see that in the output.

Comment: Thanks. I found a table delineating what hexadecimal values represent/do what, and this cleared it up.

Comment: This part of the documentation made all the difference too: "The default type of a hexadecimal value is a string."

Comment: @Gordon, Regarding "context-less is equivalent to a string context", do you have a source for this?

Comment: @Pacerier . . . The referenced documentation gives several examples.  The first is clearly context-less and a string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I mean since they didn't state it explicitly, there may be a setting or a switch that might alter this behavior.

Comment: @Pacerier . . . I would tend to doubt that there is a parameter that controls this, because it is so deeply embedded in the actual parsing of the query.  It is possible, however, as I do not know all parameters in MySQL.